# Paramiko can't find keys from ssh-agent on Windows

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, ssh-agent

I am trying to connect to a test device on my local network using paramiko and SSH. If I specify the filename of my key and its passphrase, I can connect to the device without a problem. However, since my script is meant to run on any machine that has the key added to the `ssh-agent`, I am trying to find a way around that.

`ssh-add -l` shows me that the key is active in my `ssh-agent`, but if I use the `get_keys()` method from the `paramiko.Agent`-class, there's just an empty list, meaning to me that Paramiko either can't connect to the `ssh-agent` or doesn't have the permissions to get the keys.

From shell, I can just connect to the device with `ssh root@IPADDRESS`. When I try to connect to device with Paramiko without specifying the path to the key and its passphrase, I'm just getting the *"Authentication failed"* error.

```
import paramiko
import os

def createSSHClient(server, port, user):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(server, port, username=user)
    return client

ssh = createSSHClient('IPADDRESS', 22, 'root')
```

Checking `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in `os.environ` gives me back `False`, but as far as I know, SSH on Windows doesn't quite work like on Unix/Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paramiko can talk to Windows OpenSSH `ssh-agent` since 2.10 only (and it [was buggy in 2.10.3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74698290/850848)). Make sure you have the latest version of Paramiko.

---

Older versions could talk to PuTTY Pageant only.