# Reading keys from OpenSSH auth agent on Windows with Paramiko is failing with "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent'"

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, openssh, ssh-agent

I am using simple function to list out all RSA keys using `paramiko.agent.Agent().get_keys()` function. But there is weird error:

> [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\.\pipe\openssh-ssh-agent'

Also OpenSSH server is running

```
from paramiko import agent

print(agent.Agent().get_keys())
```

Error message:
[image]

My local version of OpenSSH is:

> OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.9p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3

Answer (score 2):

paramiko==2.10.3 is [having an issue](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/2008) with connecting to OpenSSH authentication agent on Windows machine.

I upgraded it to paramiko==2.11.1 and it solved my problem. Now this version is not throwing any error like `Invalid argument: '\\\\.pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent'`